# An object thats in an array that is in an constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

When I console.log, this code:

```
 var Student = function(name, address, gpa){

    console.log(this);
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.gpa = gpa;

    console.log("name is equal to " + name);
    console.log("address is equal to " + address);
    console.log("gpa is equal to " + gpa);
};



    var studentCall = [
    new Student ({
        name: "Marshae Hannor",
        address:{
            street: "345 Main St",
            city: "Smyrna",
            state: "GA"},
        gpa: [2.5, 3.5, 4.0]}),
    new Student ({
        name: "Vernon Owens",
        address:{
            street: "439 Serious St",
            city: "Baltimore",
            state: "MD"},
        gpa: [3.5, 3.2, 3.7]})
];
```

this is what I get in the console.log

```
Object {}
main2.js (line 39)
name is equal to [object Object]
main2.js (line 44)
address is equal to undefined
main2.js (line 45)
gpa is equal to undefined
main2.js (line 46)
Object {}
main2.js (line 39)
name is equal to [object Object]
main2.js (line 44)
address is equal to undefined
main2.js (line 45)
gpa is equal to undefined
```

Can someone help me understand what Im doing incorrectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your calls to `Student`, you're passing in a *single* argument, which is an object that looks like this:

```
{
    name: "Marshae Hannor",
    address:{
        street: "345 Main St",
        city: "Smyrna",
        state: "GA"},
    gpa: [2.5, 3.5, 4.0]
}
```

But your `Student` function expects to receive three discrete arguments. So you'd call it without the `{` and `}` and without giving the names of the arguments:

```
var studentCall = [
    new Student (
        "Marshae Hannor",
        {
            street: "345 Main St",
            city: "Smyrna",
            state: "GA"},
        [2.5, 3.5, 4.0]),
    new Student (
        "Vernon Owens",
        {
            street: "439 Serious St",
            city: "Baltimore",
            state: "MD"},
        [3.5, 3.2, 3.7])
];
```

**Or**, modify `Student` to expect to receive just a single object with those properties:

```
var Student = function(obj){

    console.log(this);
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.address = obj.address;
    this.gpa = obj.gpa;

    console.log("name is equal to " + this.name);
    console.log("address is equal to " + this.address);
    console.log("gpa is equal to " + this.gpa);
};
```

Comment: Thanks TJ Crowder, your second with obj, worked. Thanks a million! I wholeheartedly appreciate it! Can't thank you enough right now and I understand it, sorry but I've only been coding for a month in a half. Thanks so much

Comment: @user2956271: No apology required! I'm glad this helped. Keep at it, you clearly have the knack.

Comment: Wow that is such a compliment, especially coming from someone who have been doing this for the amount of time you have. I will keep at it, I know I want to do web developing for life. Thanks for the compliment.